# Connect MSSQL by Python and AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, pyodbc

I am trying to connect a python function in lambda on AWS environment, to an MSSQL database. without results.

I'm using the pyodbc library. but it is giving me many problems.

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.parser import parse
from os import getenv
import pyodbc 

conn =pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={./libmsodbcsql-13.0.so.1.0};SERVER='+rds_host+';DATABASE='+db_name+';UID='+name+';PWD='+password+'')
```

Zip Folder

[image]

Lambda error

[image]

Test the connection in docker using amazonlinux image and it works.

Please help

Comment: Did you check the [tutorial from the documentation itself](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pyodbc?view=sql-server-2017). Your connection string uses a file path instead of an actual driver name. You should probably try to connect to a SQL Server database locally before deploying to AWS.

Comment: the local connection works without problems.